# not able to transfer Image file

Tags: java

hi this is my client program for transfering  Image , while transfering the image file it is getting corrupted , not able to open that image file , i'm not able to identify the bug , can any one help me.

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

System.out.println("Writing.......");

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Blue hills.jpg");

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
int bytes = 0;

while ((bytes = fstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}

in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `s` is a `Socket` and you're attempting to transfer a file over the network? Here's an example of sending a file with sockets. It just sets up a server socket in a thread and connects to itself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3434);
                Socket socket = ss.accept();
                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.jpg");
                copy(in, out);
                out.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3434);
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("in.jpg");
    copy(in, out);
    out.close();
    in.close();
}

public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: Locally or between computers? I verified that it works locally for me.